# Get jQuery image crossfade to stop on hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, slideshow

I have created a "loop" of images using jQuery, and I want it to stop when hovering but don't really know where to go from here. The loop switches images without fading between them, so that's not the problem. I'm pretty new to jQuery and although I've begun to grasp the concept, I'm far from good at it.

Right now the script looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('#cycler .active');
     var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
  $next.css('z-index',2);
  $active.fadeOut(0,function(){
  $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
      $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval('cycleImages()', 120);

})
</script>
```

I would be so happy if someone could explain how to continue from here!

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTimer; 

function pauseLoop(){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function startLoop(){
    myTimer = setInterval(cycleImages, 120);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    startLoop();
    $("#cycler").hover(pauseLoop, startLoop)
})
```

Encapsulate the setInterval() in functions to start and stop it, then trigger the start/pause functions.

Hopefully this can get you going. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm! Now when I see how this actually looks like, I think it would work better if the loop starts again directly on the next image, instead of waiting the time left on the last one. Do you know if this would be really complicated, or something someone like me could understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTimer; 

function pauseLoop(){
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function startLoop(){
    cycleImages();
    myTimer = setInterval(cycleImages, 120);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    myTimer = setInterval(cycleImages, 120);
    $("#cycler").hover(pauseLoop, startLoop);
})
```

A little mod to the code should do it.
On the "$(document).ready" function we just auto start the timer which kicks off the slideshow. Then on a restart we run your "cycleImages()" function then restart the timer.